# calculate annualized return, annualized standard deviation and Beta from19 monthly return values

Tags: excel, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a list of 19 monthly returns for an investment in Excel. I have a
second list of 19 monthly returns for its associated benchmark index in Excel.

How do I calculate the annualized return, annualized standard deviation,
and Beta from those 19 values for both the investment and the benchmark index?

What would the Excel formula be?

Below is what the data looks like in Excel (CSV format)
(NOTE: this website removes newlines):

```
month,fund return,benchmark return
1,-3%,-3.22%
2,8.92%,10.02%
3,2.59%,3.23%
4,-0.19%,-0.16%
5,3.10%,3.39%
6,5.45%,4.40%
7,8.14%,7.64%
8,1.06%,0.59%
9,2.61%,2.55%
10,4.43%,4.12%
11,2.05%,1.83%
12,-5.68%,-5.45%
13,7.04%,7.08%
14,-1.10%,-2.46%
15,9.79%,9.45%
16,-7.84%,-8.29%
17,-3.81%,-3.86%
18,6.61%,6.43%
19,-3.73%,-4.24%
```

[image]

Comment: It would be good to post few sample data as text table and show your desired output and then explain logic to gain that output.

Comment: How would you do the calculation for one by hand? How would you then structure that in Excel?

Comment: Please provide the data in a form that we can copy and paste into Excel.